# tricky theoretical question about input resolution(logic)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

i happen to have a theoretical question about input resolution in logic.

so in input resolution we can use the resolution rule/theorem if at least one out of two clauses in the resolution are from the from the original proposition.

now my question is this: is the input resolution complete to contradiction?

i mean, If you take a claim(proposition) that is a result from the knowledge base and add its contradiction(negation) to the knowledge base, then can we deduct an empty proposition(contradiction) using the inference rules?

would really interested in learning from your inputs. really curious

Comment: See [Input resolution](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/notes/chapter_12.html) : "input resolution is complete for Horn clauses but incomplete in general",

Comment: thank you very much. do you know where can i find a formal proof to that? hopefully by negation if possible. really interested in seeing the process and learning from it

Comment: In the above link, we have the counterexample showing how the proof procedure is not complete. For completeness, see [Henschen & Wos, 1974](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=321857).

Comment: do you happen to have a non paid link, or can you please post the counterexample? it asks me to purchase it